# Forms in PHP not displaying

Tags: php, html, forms

Using this exact code I've been able to create text fields in HTML, but when I convert (rename) the file to PHP the field dissapears. Why does this happen and how do I stop it?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>StatsCalc V1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Buttons.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
      <form>
        <input type="text" class="writies" name="writy1" />
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your PHP code?

Comment: Try adding a closing `</html>`

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe some misconfiguration of your webserver. Are there some errors, maybe in the logs?

Comment: enable error_reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see what error are returning.

Comment: It could be a webserver error, I'll have to look that up. @Tyteen there isn't any yet. It's going to be added once I've customised the input (I'm building calculators for different statistical models so I can save time on maths homework + revise IT).

I'll follow your advice PSantos, that's a good idea.

Comment: I'm going to write different HTML docs with links to the form handling, since I know from experience that that works reliably. I'd prefer integrated + debugged PHP, but the server I'm running makes that difficult (see my response to Bogdan below). Thanks for the help, and you can vote to delete this if you want.

Comment: I was changing the wrong file. I am a moron.

Answer (score 0):

make a new file index.php write in it the bellow code and if it shows something you have php installed if not you don't have. 
To have php installed you either install manually apache + php or you download a ready made application like xampp or ampps or easyphp which will provide you with everything you need to begin learning php.
[tutorial for install of course you can choose any other.](http://www.bogotobogo.com/php/apache_php_mysql.php)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: I definitely have PHP installed, I've written another document that was 100% dependant on it (most of my markup was in the PHP, as was page management). I think the safest thing to do here is to make a reference PHP file for the form handling and keep the markup in HTML. 

It would be VERY impractical for me to dig around the server since it's mostly hidden from the admin (EasyPHP Webserver) and is apparently broken (the backend Service Manager "doesn't exist" - unfortunately, it is the only way to get at error logs and stuff like that).